# ios 8 UICollectionView crashing sometimes after delete item

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView working fine, iOS8

when I delete an item sometimes the app crashes with:

> 'UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index
>   path that does not exist:  {length =
>   2, path = 0 - 39}'

this is how it the collectionView works
1. show collection view fine
2. tap on item on collection view
3. push VC with info about item
4. tap "delete" on info VC, this sends delegate to first VC [with collection view], and pops VC
5. delegate gets called to delete item,
6. some times work, wome times crashes

```
- (void)itemIgnored
{

    [self performSelector:@selector(updateCollectionView) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0 ];

} 

- (void)updateCollectionView
{
    [self.itemsArr removeObjectAtIndex:self.indexPath.row];

    [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:self.indexPath]];

    [self.collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
}
```

I have searched a lot about this problem, have tried,

> [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];

Also this is my only collectionview, no sharing collectionViewLayout
but not working either ,
what is the probem? .)

Comment: Try wrap your collection view operations into the collection views performBatchUpdates block

Comment: @DanielGalasko thanks for the comment, I did try performBatchUpdates but still crashing randomly :(

Comment: try deleting your reloadSections line, don't think its necessary. Why delete an item then reload the section, you could also delete the item from the array and then call reloadSection but definitely not the two collectionView statements consecutively]